# How to filter NX ESLint output by rule?

Tags: angular, eslint, nxwl

I am trying to fix a specific rule in a project (`@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries`), for this I want to be able to run `nx lint` and somehow let ESLint know I just want to see warnings of that rule.

Is this possible? I can not find anything related to it.